# Помогите, у меня проблема с localhost и XAMPP

Tags: php, html, xampp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ничего не помогло мне, не знаю что делать, прошу помогите я устал

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А что у вас в папке project?

Answer (score 0):

Проверь в файле `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` (у меня в самом низу) есть ли что-то вроде:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\project"
    ServerName project.loc
    ServerAlias www.project.loc
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\project">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Если нету, попробуй добавить (предварительно выключив Apache).
Соответсвенно ссылка будет `project.loc`